# how to hide html tags on edit form in php

Tags: html

i have one doubt. I am submitting form data in codeigniter.After submit form data again am trying to edit the data 
the text area field is showing like below format with html tags.When am submit data in to database one by one showing data
in form so that am using br tag while insert the data in to the database. After edit the form it will showing 
tags also. But i want to hide the br tags and if i edit the line again i want to store the data in database line by line with br tag.

```
ALL EXTRAS TO BE PAID DIRECTLY  <br />
 Booked and Payable By: Hotelbeds <br />
 ALL EXTRAS TO BE PAID DIRECTLY  <br />
 Booked and Payable By: Hotelbeds <br />
 ALL EXTRAS TO BE PAID DIRECTLY  <br />
 Booked and Payable By: Hotelbeds <br />
```

Answer (score 0):

> When am submit data in to database one by one showing data in form so that am using br tag while insert the data in to the database

This is your problem. Don't do that.

Store the user input in the database, exactly as it is provided by the user.

When you pull it out of the database, then apply your formatting *in the fashion that is appropriate for where you are displaying it*. This will be different when you render it in the "final" view (where you want to add line breaks) and the "edit" view (where you are putting it in a textarea and need literal new lines).

Comment: we are not stored in database. Already we are getting data from other database like this ..     `ALL EXTRAS TO BE PAID DIRECTLY  <br /><br /><br /><br />
 Booked and Payable By: EXPEDIA <br /><br /><br /><br />
 ISSUED AS PER TERMS AND CONDITIONS (DETAILS INSIDE VOUCHER JACKET)`

Comment: Here i need to get data on edit form and again update data , when am show form on edit i need to remove the br tags and after made any change again i need to add br tag . How can i do please tell me